# GWT Super Dev Mode arguments

Tags: java, gwt

Tell me what is better to use for debugging in superDevMode 2.8.2

style

- OBF (for obfuscated), the default
- PRETTY, which makes the output readable to a human
- DETAILED, which improves on PRETTY with even more detail (such as very verbose variable names)

What are the best options to use for superDevMode and production

Now I'm like this

```
-logLevel DEBUG -noincremental
```

[image]

And for production

```
gwt {
  gwtVersion = "2.8.2"
  modules "com.test.Device"
  maxHeapSize = "8G"

  compiler {
    compileReport = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Best in order to achieve what? If you want to see while debugging what you're debugging, then PRETTY or DETAILED is helpful